# Logback midday logs rotation

Tags: java, logback

Im' using logback and I need to rotate logs twice a day at midnight and mid day.
Logback version 1.4.11

I configured a TimeBasedRollingPolicy with fileNamePattern "myfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-a}.log"
The log are still rotated only at midnight !!

How to configure midday rotation ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.